# What are the neighborhoods, closed, open sets and sets that are dense, of the following metric space.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I have the following metric, for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
d(x,y) = \begin{cases} |x|+|y|,\quad &\text{if } x\ne y \\
0 &\text{if } x = y \\
\end{cases}
$$
I proved that is a metric space, I just want to have an idea what are the neighborhoods, open sets, close sets and dense sets.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\neq 0$, the set $\left\{x\right\}$ is open. A basic neighbourhood of $0$ has the form $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

With this, you can check that a set $A$ is open if either $0\not\in A$, or if there is some $\epsilon$ with $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq A$.

The only dense subsets are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{ 0\}$.

Comment: Did you mean $\{ x\} $?

Comment: @Ian Yes, thanks

Comment: Why is$ \mathbb{R} -{0} $ a dense set?

Comment: @FernandoBetancourtVélez Because there is a sequence of nonzero points which converges to zero.

Comment: @Ian I know that's not what you meant, but I think it is important to mention that not every set which has a sequence of nonzero points converging to zero is dense. I'm just being a little pedantic :)

Comment: Well, "because the only point missing is zero, which has a sequence of nonzero points converging to it". I guess that's better.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. $\phantom{}$